# Training vs Testing with Queues

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm using the setup described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/how_tos/reading_data/index.html) to load some training images in batches, i.e., basically this:

```
def read_my_file_format(filename_queue):
  # ... use a reader + a decoder

def input_pipeline(filenames, batch_size, num_epochs=None):
  filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(...)
  example, label = read_my_file_format(filename_queue)
  example_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
      [example, label], batch_size=batch_size, ...)
  return example_batch, label_batch

def build_net():
    batch, label = input_pipeline(...)
    y = encoder(batch)  # <- build network using the batch

def train():
  with tf.Session() as sess:
    # ... init vars

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    try:
      while not coord.should_stop():
        # ... training step

    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
        print('Done training -- epoch limit reached')
    finally:
        coord.request_stop()

    coord.join(threads)
    sess.close()
```

That's all good for training - however, I don't see how I can test the resulting network! What confuses me:

- The tensor returned by `input_pipeline` is part of the network. For testing, I would have to replace it?
- I'm thinking I could create another `input_pipeline` for testing, i.e., with a different filenames queue. Then I could use a `tf.cond` to switch between the different input batches, but then: how do I ensure that only one queue is depleted at a time. I don't see how to access the different queues and how to specify how they are unloaded.

---

**Basically**, this question boils down to: what's the canonical way to test a network built using the `tf.train.shuffle_batch` approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are definitely on the right track with the idea of creating an additional input pipeline for the dataset evaluation. Using [multiple input pipelines](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/how_tos/reading_data/index.html#multiple-input-pipelines) is one of the recommended approaches, which would consist of two processes — training on one and eval on the another. Checkpoints would be used during the training process, then every thousand steps, the code can attempt to [`eval`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/mnist/tf/index.html#evaluate-the-model) the model against both the training and test datasets.

<sub>*quoted from documentation:*</sub>

> - The training process reads training input data and periodically    writes checkpoint files with all the trained variables.
> - The evaluation process restores the checkpoint files into an inference model that reads validation input data.

It's also possible to eval even after training has completed/exited. ([see this example](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/deep_cnn/index.html#save-and-restore-checkpoints))

Another consideration is that by [sharing variables](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/how_tos/variable_scope/index.html) train and eval can operate in the same graph in the same process, while sharing their trained variables!

Regarding the queue depletion concern you have, if you set num_threads bigger than 1 with `tf.train.shuffle_batch*` it reads from a single file at the same time (+ faster than with 1 thread), instead of N files at once, (see the section on [batching](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/how_tos/reading_data/index.html#batching)).

Answer (score 1):

My idea would be to use a string placeholder, that is, assuming that you have multiple input files:

```
filenames_place = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[None])
num_epochs_place = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
example_batch, label_batch = input_pipeline(filenames_place, batch_size, num_epochs_place)
...
try:
   sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={filenames_place: ["train_data1", "train_data2"], num_epochs_place=5})

except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
    print('Done training -- epoch limit reached')

sess.run(eval_op, feed_dict={filenames_place: ["test_data"], num_epochs_place=1})
```

Comment: Does this actually work though? I feel like the filenames cannot be changed after the `string_input_producer` is created, not sure about that though